# MacBook not showing full storage

Tags: macos, ssd, ventura

My MacBook is the MacBook Pro 16" with 512GB of storage, but I am only able to use 374GB of it. I checked diskutil and this is what I get. Anyone know how to get rid of the 'free space' and put it back to where I can get my full storage? I am on MacOS Ventura. I've already tried formatting the drive but it still didn't give me the right amount.
[image]

Comment: Enter `diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3` followed by `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`.

Comment: That worked thank you so much!